# Group by / Order by

Tags: sql

[Excel Image Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYBCo.png) I have this SQL statement to show approval area by department and the count on workflow approvals or denials that are returned. My current statement is as follows as well as with what it is currently producing, followed by how I want it to look. It has something to do with the group by and order by but I cannot figure out how to change the order to my desire. Any help is appreciated. I have attached an image to show the current outcome vs. the desire outcome.

```
    SELECT DECODE(SUBSTR(P.DESCR,1,18),'Chartfield Signers','Chartfield Signers',P.DESCR), DECODE(U.EOAWSTEP_STATUS,'A','Approval','Denial'), COUNT(U.EOAWSTEP_INSTANCE), TO_CHAR(AVG(
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM (U.EOAWDTTM_MODIFIED - U.DTTM_CREATED) DAY TO SECOND ) +
    (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (U.EOAWDTTM_MODIFIED - U.DTTM_CREATED) DAY TO SECOND ) / 24) +
    (EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (U.EOAWDTTM_MODIFIED - U.DTTM_CREATED) DAY TO SECOND ) / (60*24)) +
    (EXTRACT(SECOND FROM (U.EOAWDTTM_MODIFIED - U.DTTM_CREATED) DAY TO SECOND ) / (60*60*24))),'999.99') "DURATION IN DAYS"
    FROM PS_EOAW_STEPINST S  , PS_EOAW_STEP P  , PS_MDA_EPAF_WFXREF T  , PS_EOAW_USERINST U
    WHERE T.EOAWPRCS_ID LIKE 'MDA_EPAF%'
    AND T.EOAWTHREAD_ID = S.EOAWTHREAD_ID
    AND T.EOAWPRCS_ID = S.EOAWPRCS_ID
    AND S.EOAWSTEP_INSTANCE = U.EOAWSTEP_INSTANCE
    AND U.EOAWSTEP_STATUS IN ('A','D')
    AND P.EOAWPRCS_ID = S.EOAWPRCS_ID
    AND P.EOAWDEFN_ID = S.EOAWDEFN_ID
    AND P.EFFDT = S.EFFDT
    AND U.DTTM_CREATED between to_date(:d1, 'dd-mon-yy' )
             and to_date(:d2, 'dd-mon-yy' )
    AND P.EOAWSTAGE_NBR = S.EOAWSTAGE_NBR
    AND P.EOAWPATH_ID = S.EOAWPATH_ID
    AND P.EOAWSTEP_NBR = S.EOAWSTEP_NBR
    GROUP BY DECODE(SUBSTR(P.DESCR,1,18),'Chartfield Signers','Chartfield Signers',P.DESCR),DECODE(U.EOAWSTEP_STATUS,'A','Approval','Denial')
    ORDER BY DECODE(SUBSTR(P.DESCR,1,18),'Chartfield Signers','Chartfield Signers',P.DESCR),DECODE(U.EOAWSTEP_STATUS,'A','Approval','Denial');
```

Comment: I see code but no images. Is SO saying you don't have enough reputation to post pictures?

Comment: The very first 3 words "Excel image reference" is the picture

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses your initial query (most of it is left out to reduce length) as a CTE, and then adds a pivot section, which is what you need to get Approval and Denial in their own columns.

```
    --Be sure to put a ; before WITH
--Don't miss the ) at the end of the section

;WITH Main AS (
SELECT DECODE(SUBSTR(P.DESCR,1,18),'Chartfield Signers','Chartfield Signers',P.DESCR) AS Descr
    , DECODE(U.EOAWSTEP_STATUS,'A','Approval','Denial') AS AppDen
    , COUNT(U.EOAWSTEP_INSTANCE) AS CountAD, TO_CHAR(AVG(
    EXTRACT ...
    ...
    GROUP BY Descr, AppDen
/*    ORDER BY DECODE(SUBSTR(P.DESCR,1,18),'Chartfield Signers','Chartfield Signers',P.DESCR)
        ,DECODE(U.EOAWSTEP_STATUS,'A','Approval','Denial')*/
)
--I didn't see anywhere the string Stage was set, but I see it in your desired output.  
--I've just added it as a separate variable

--In your code you have Approvals and Denials in separate records.  You need to pivot
--Approval and Denial to be columns on the same row.  The PIVOT function will do that
--It takes some getting used to.  You should try and become familiar with it online or otherwise

--The two COALESCE functions allow sql to use a 0 in the Approval and Denial columns when there
--is no Approval or Denial row for a given descr.

,PivotTable AS (
SELECT Stage
      ,Descr
      ,[Approval]
      ,[Denial]
  FROM (SELECT Stage, Descr
      ,COALESCE([Approval],0) AS [Approval]
      ,COALESCE([Denial],0) AS [Denial]
      FROM (SELECT Stage, Descr, AppDen, [CountAD]
            FROM Main) AS so
        PIVOT(SUM(CountAD) FOR AppDen IN (
             [Approval]
            ,[Denial]
        )) AS p) AS p
) 

--since the values in duration are not the same for the one example you gave us of
--a descr with both approval and denial, you can't include that in the pivot section.
--I've added this next section to insert the duration of the Approval row. 
--You may need to adjust it for however you want to determine Duration

SELECT pt.Stage
    , pt.Descr
    , pt.Approval
    , pt.Denial
    , m.Duration 
    FROM PivotTable AS pt
        LEFT JOIN Main AS m ON pt.Stage = m.Stage
            AND pt.Descr = m.Descr
            AND m.AppDen = 'Approval'
  ORDER BY pt.Stage, pt.Descr
```

(I used aliases for your initial declaration of variables to avoid repeating code in the GROUP BY section.  If your calculation of a variable changes, you don't want to have to scroll through code to find all the different places where you need to change it.)